# XSLT to copy XML doc and add attribute plus generated value under certain conditions

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm pretty new to XSLT and have an urgent work requirement that I'm finding quite complex to sort out.

I have an XML doc which needs an attribute adding under certain conditions.

The XML doc is pretty straightforward:

```
<A x="foo" y="bar" z="">
<B/>
<C/></A>
```

Basically if attribute "z" is present.  Then a new attribute needs to be added to node "A".  The value of the attribute needs to be a text string with the values of "x" and "y" substituted at certain places.  The result should look like:

```
<A x="foo" y="bar" z="" new="values present are x=foo and y=bar">
<B/>
<C/></A>
```

I've gotten as far as creating an XSLT that will copy the document to the attribute level.  But I'm stumbling when trying to create the logic that tests for attribute z and creates a string based on x and y.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Also - apologies if my code formatting sucks

**From comments:**

> There's something that's stopping
>   these solutions working. The text XML
>   I've put above actually has a root
>   node `<R>` that contains it all. The R
>   node has an attribute like this :
>   `xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4"`.
>   Adding this attribute for some reason
>   causes the template matching "A" to
>   not work?!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the shortest so far solution that is also fully in the spirit of XSLT. :)

Comment: There's something that's stopping these solutions working.  The text XML I've put above actually has a root node <R> that contains it all.  The R node has an attribute like this : xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4".  Adding this attribute for some reason causes the template matching "A" to not work?!

Comment: Yes, this is very important. I have edited my answer to work with this new XML document. Please, edit your question!

Comment: Unless you add this important information in your question, you are misleading everyone !!!!

Comment: the reason why it is an important detail is because that attribute is special. It is an XML namespace attribute, which affects how the `<R>` element (and it's descendants) are processed.  They belong to that namespace, so XPATH statements must be adjusted to correctly match the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**: The OP has explained (only in a comment!):

> There's something that's stopping
>   these solutions working. The text XML
>   I've put above actually has a root
>   node  that contains it all. The `<R>`
>   node has an attribute like this :
>   `xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4"`.
>   Adding this attribute for some reason
>   causes the template matching "A" to
>   not work?!

**This is probably as short as it can be**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4"
 xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4" exclude-result-prefixes="x">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="x:A[@z]">
  <A new="values present are x={@x} and y={@y}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </A>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<R xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4">
    <A x="foo" y="bar" z="">
        <B/>
        <C/>
    </A>
</R>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<R xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4">
    <A new="values present are x=foo and y=bar" x="foo" y="bar" z="">
        <B></B>
        <C></C>
    </A>
</R>
```

Comment: thanks Dimitre.  I somehow figured out the xmlns prob, and I saw you'd given the fullest answer. And I'll add additional stuff to the question next time! Thanks v much

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="A">
    <A>
      <xsl:if test="@z">
        <xsl:attribute name="new">
         <xsl:value-of select="concat('values present are x=',@x,' and y=',@y)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </A>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you! that's awesome.  I just have one tweak...  node A is not actually the root..  it's contained in the root node (let's say "R").  It only works if I take A out and make it the root node as in the example above.  I've tried changing the match="A" to match="/R/A" but to no effect.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Now with correct namespace.

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:fixml="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="fixml:A/@z">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="new">
            <xsl:value-of
               select="concat('values present are x=',../@x,' and y=',../@y)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<R xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4">
    <A x="foo" y="bar" z="">
        <B/>
        <C/>
    </A>
</R>
```

Output:

```
<R xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4">
    <A x="foo" y="bar" z="" new="values present are x=foo and y=bar">
        <B></B>
        <C></C>
    </A>
</R>
```